# How does one prove the following integration formula

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(z)\exp(-w z^2)-1}{z^2}dz=-\sqrt{\pi w}\,\exp\left(-\frac{1}{4w}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}\right)$$where  w is positive and erf is the error function.

Comment: How do you have a $z$ in the final expression? I guess it should be some constant, perhaps, $2$?

Comment: Call it $f(w)$ and consider $f'(w)$.

Comment: It should be $-\sqrt{\pi w}$ at the beginning,  not $-\sqrt{\pi z}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo - corrected already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lt us write $$2I(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos z~ e^{-w z^2}-1}{z^2} dz.$$ Differentiate w.r. $w$, then
$$-2I'(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos z ~ e^{-w z^2} dz= \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-((wz^2-iz)} dz= e^{-1/(4w)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-wt^2} dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{w} }\exp[-\frac{1}{4w}].$$ Integrating by letting $w=1/u^2$, we get
$$-2I(w)=2\sqrt{\pi w} \exp[-\frac{1}{4w}]+\pi~ \mbox{erf}[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}] +C$$
Note that $$2I(0)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos z-1}{z^2}dz=-\pi \Rightarrow C=0.$$
Hence $$I(w)=-\sqrt{\pi w}\exp[\frac{-1}{4w}]-\frac{\pi}{2} \mbox{erf}[-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}}].$$